# If $p$ is a limit point of $E$, $f$ is continuous at $p$ $\iff$ $\lim _{x\to p} f(x) = f(p)$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $p$ is a limit point of $E$, $f$ is continuous at $p$ $\iff$ $\lim _{x\to p} f(x) = f(p)$

The above is Theorem 4.6 in Rudin.

Then, what happens if $p$ is not a limit point of $E?$

I think even if $p$ is not a limit point, still $f$ is continuous at $p \iff x\to p f(x) = f(p).$

Any counterexample?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify where $p$ lives, and what the domain and codomain of $f$ are? It would also be good to use Latex, which you can do by enclosing your mathematics in $'s.

Comment: If $p$ is not a limit point, that is, if $p$ is isolated, then there is nothing to be worry about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is not a limit point of $E, E$ a metric space and the domain of $f:E\to X$, $X$ another metric space, then the only sequences in $E$ that converge to $p$ are eventually always equal to $p$. So on the one hand, you're right, but on the other hand, $f$ is *always* continuous at an isolated point of its domain. So this case isn't interesting. The same result holds in general topological spaces, but I think Rudin won't be in that setting.